# replace attenuators in filters with changing gain of each filters?

Tags: filter, active-filter, attenuator, attenuation

I have multiple filters that are all the same gain that are all attenuated differently with the same attenuator circuit. Is it possible to replace the attenuators with just changing the gain of each filter to match the output as if they had the attenuators?

Below is what the filters and the attenuators are configured in the circuit :

[image: attenuator filter circuit]

Comment: "Is it possible..." Yes, but what are you trying to achieve? Maybe you will not like the side effects, so it is best to be clear about the aims of the circuit.

Comment: Why are the attenuators there in the first place? What is the system they are in? Always take the time to understand a system first, and only then, propose changes to it (Chesterton's Fence).

Comment: @TimWilliams I should mention the filters and attenuators are a for a vocoder design. I have seen other vocoder filter designs that various filters have different gain? Which I believe is for audio equalization?

Comment: Ah, okay. So they'll have a zillion channels of these? And you're wondering if it's easier to put the attenuator inside the filter? Probably not: changing gain of the filter also changes its time constants, so, many components need to change. The attenuator out front is easier to adjust, then: just one or two resistors to set each channel.